# Cypress - Why Siblings function execute first before the XHR loads

Tags: jquery, vue.js, cypress

I have been trying Cypress on vue.js apps and have noticed that when siblings function are used, the XHR loads after the function is executed, this is causing the assertion to fail.

For eg. This one throws error on siblings and after that XHR loads, causing failure at siblings()

```
cy.get('mydatatable').find('td').children().siblings('.classname').contains('mytext').should('be.visible')
```

On the same web-part, this one works fine

```
cy.get('mydatatable').find('td').contains('mytext').should('have.attr','class','classname')
```

Can anyone explains to me why ?

Comment: Do that Td have many classes name in children?

Comment: @N.. - This table is in Vuejs so many class name appears at the run time.